# In Rspec, how to test that a Mailer raises an error?

Tags: rspec, actionmailer

Given a simple Rails mailer that raises an exception, how do I write a rspec spec that confirms that the exception is raised?

```
# status_mailer.rb
  ...
  def simple_message(addr, subject, msg_text)
    raise "Foo"
  end
  ...
```

and

```
#status_mailer_spec.rb
RSpec.describe StatusMailer, type: :mailer do

  describe "simple_message"  do
    it "always raises exception" do
      expect{
        StatusMailer.simple_message("a@example.com", "a subject", "a message")
      }.to raise_error("wtf")
    end
  end
end
```

Gives the result:

```
expected Exception with "wtf" but nothing was raised
```

But, pretty obviously, whenever the mailer method gets invoked, it does indeed raise "Foo".

(This is an intentionally failing spec for purposes of figuring this out, but I expected it to report the **wrong** error was raised, eg, 'Foo' instead pf 'wtf'. But it says no error was raised.)

I'm using Rails 5.0.1 and Rspec 3.5.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `deliver_now` in the spec:

```
StatusMailer.simple_message("a@example.com", "a subject", "a message").deliver_now
```

Comment: doh, yes, the exception wouldn't be thrown until delivery was attempted.